# css or styles inside imported npm ui componnent library not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js

My ui component library is developed as vue js plugin with bootstrap and bootstrap-vue and i am importing this in another vue js project which also uses bootstrap and bootstrap-vue. This projects runs standalone without an issue.

I have some sample html below which works fine when run the plugin standalone.

```
  <div class="row">
    <h5>this is h5 header</h5>
    <h1>this is h1 header</h1>
  </div>
```

But when i import this npm package in another app some styles are not loading or overwritten.

Below are the styles rendered inside my main app browser .

```
  .row[data-v-7d767f7c] {
    text-align: left;
  }
  .row {
    display: -ms-flexbox;//striked out
    display: -webkit-box;//striked out
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;//striked out
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
  }
```

I tried to look where the issue is and when inspected the div element not rendering as expected i see the div block style is striked out by user agent style. A screenshot is attached below.

[image]

If i don't import bootstrap library again in my main app where ui plugin is used then my plugin ui elements render fine..

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to see, but that screenshot is showing your style working. The base display value for a div is `block`, by the user agent. That was replaced because of the `row` class to be `flex`, which is the current value, which matches the css you posted above the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Got the issue resolved. i have one place where i am using custom css and its class names are conflicting with bootstrap class names.